# How can I sort the elements in gridMenu in ui-grid angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

```
vm.gridOptions = {
    exporterMenuCsv: false,
    enableGridMenu: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name' },
      { name: 'gender' },
      { name: 'company' }
    ]
```

I want to sort the columns in gridMenu alphetically, is there any inbuilt property for these or I need to write a custom method for sorting that.